# Why does the "objects: [PFObject]?" parameter of Parse's findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock function return nil?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, null, pfobject

This is for an existing class on Parse called "HellsKitchen" and I have tried others, but always receive nil on objects.

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "HellsKitchen")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("got em: \(objects)")
        } else {
            print("error: \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

All of the other posts about this refer to the block closure when they had objects as [AnyObject]? but it has since changed sometime in late 2015 and I no longer need to cast it as PFObject as all the answers say.

I have tried adding App Transport Security Settings > Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES to my Info.plist to no avail.

I get no error from the block either. It passes into the if statement because error == nil and prints "got em: nil".

How can I get my objects?

Comment: Try simply using objects in the parameters without a specific type (remove : [PFObject]?. Also - are you sure that you have data stored within that class? If you don't, that would be why objects is set to nil.

Comment: Simply using objects still returns nil and I am sure there is data in the class.